# Batch adding extra clause

Tags: batch-file

This is my first time really editing a batch-file.
See my script below which moves all files (except first file from month) to a folder.  Now I'd like it to keep all files from current month in folder, so it should not loop and move files.

```
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=D:\ftproot\ftp_db-backup\"
SET /a month=99
SET /a year=99
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "skip=4tokens=1,2,3,5,*delims=/- " %%a IN (
  'dir /tc /a-d /-c /od "*" '
  ) DO (
IF "%%d"=="" GOTO done
 IF %%b-%%c neq !month!-!year! (
  ECHO(leave "%%e" "%sourcedir%" 
      SET month=%%b
      SET year=%%c

     ) ELSE (
//please note I removed the MOVE part here, it should be right here as the echo shows.

      ECHO(MOVE "%%e" "D:\ftproot\ftp_db-backup\__REMOVE\" )

    )
:done
POPD


GOTO :EOF
```

What should I add, and what is the correct syntax to get it to work?

I tried adding `IF "%%d"=="08" ECHO(this is current month) ELSE GOTO done`

but that claims ELSE is incorrect.

Comment: To make it more clear perhaps, we need to keep all backups from the current month.

Comment: Try `IF "%%d"=="08" (ECHO this is current month) ELSE (echo last)` (note the positions of `(`).

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=u:\sourcedir"
SET /a month=99
SET /a year=99
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "skip=4tokens=1,2,3,5,*delims=/- " %%a IN (
  'dir /a-d /tc /-c /od "*" '
  ) DO (
 IF "%%d"=="" GOTO done
 IF "%%b-%%c" equ "%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4%" GOTO done
 IF %%b-%%c neq !month!-!year! (
  ECHO(leave "%%e" ".\x\"
  SET month=%%b
  SET year=%%c
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO(MOVE "%%e" ".\x\"
 )
)
:done
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Ah! my favourite - or at least one of them.

Received an angry phone call from someone who'd used one of my software modules. "It didn't work" "Could have cost us millions." Yeah - turns out they'd used a version modified by a third party who'd left my copyright notice and contact details in-place but hadn't bothered including a notice about their modifications....

Then there was the company which broke their commercial confidentiality agreement with me and gave my rival a copy of my software - which the rival included in their own software without attributing copyright rights - nor even acknowledgement. Fortuantely, they were unable to sell any further implementations of the software, due entirely to their incapacity to understand the business problems to be solved. They'd prefer to get their customers to change their business practices. Astonishingly, their customers seemed to meekly comply. After a few years of effort, they let the project drop entirely - after all, it was the business owner's loss, not theirs. They'd been paid to try (and fail) to understand the system, and it was no skin off of their noses for the boss to lose a few hundred thousand.

So I never again released source code to customers.

As for the current situation:

`echo(` is an undocumented form of the `echo` statement that allows `echo(%emptyvalue%` to produce an empty line, whereas `echo %emptyvalue%` will report `echo is on/off`. The parenthesis as a `part` of the `echo` statement and play no part in the matching-parentheses count. Hence the problem with the `else` - it follows at a point which is not the `if not` part of an `if` statement - becaues the `echo(` does not open a parenthesised statement-sequence. The `(` is invisible.

As to the easy solution, restoring the original version; all that's needed is the new line

```
 IF "%%b-%%c" equ "%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4%" GOTO done
```

so that the routine is forcefully terminated (and hence the files not `move`d) if the month-year of the file equals the month-year of the current date. The `/od` on the `dir` forces sorting in date-order, so the first time that the current date is found in the file-list must mean that the remaining files must also have a date-created of the current month-date, hence there's no point in checking them - they are to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "Y="
set "M="
 FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Year^,Month /Format:table') DO (

    if not defined Y set "Y=%%B"
    if not defined M set "M=%%A"

 )

 if %M% lss 10 set M=0%M% 
 echo current month : %Y%%M%

 for %%a in (.) do (
    set "drive=%%~da"
    set "d_path=%%~fa\"
 )

 set d_path=%d_path:~2%
 set d_path=%d_path:\=\\%


 rem wmic  datafile where "drive='%drive%' and path like '%d_path%'" get CreationDate,Name

 for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('"wmic  datafile where (drive='%drive%' and path like '%d_path%') get CreationDate^,Name"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%y in ("%%f") do (
      set "file_date=%%y"
      set "file_path=%%z"
      set file_ym=!file_date:~0,6!
      echo the file !file_path!  has !file_ym! creation date
      if "!file_ym!" NEQ "%Y%%M%" (
        MOVE "!file_path!" "D:\ftproot\ftp_db-backup\__REMOVE\" 
      )

    )

 )

 endlocal
```